# How to speed up Drupal 7 calls to _theme_process_registry?

Tags: 7, performance, debugging

Using [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) php profiler I can see there is much more then 100000 calls to **function_exists** 
each time user accesses a Drupal 7.8 page, mostly from **_theme_process_registry**.

What to do to limit the number of or cache these calls ?

Comment: I found there is already an issue related to this on drupal.org http://drupal.org/node/519940 Performance: optimize building theme registry by using get_defined_functions() instead of function_exists()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there is already an issue related to this on drupal.org: [Performance: optimize building theme registry by using get_defined_functions() instead of function_exists()](http://drupal.org/node/519940)